# Arduino (C++) concatenate Char* array with float array

Tags: c++, string, char

OK, so I have a set of sensors connected to an ESP8266 WiFi SoC which will populate an array with floats.  I then need to concatenate that with an array of mqtt topics before publishing via an MQTT client.  I have created a bare bones sketch as follows to try and solve an issue with the array / char manipulation:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

float readingsArray[10]; //Store the sensor readings
float reading; // Current reading 
char* mqttPackage; // The concatenated output.
char* sensorIDArray[] = { // Used for the MQTT topic string
  "DS18B20_1",
  "DS18B20_2",
  "DS18B20_3",
  "DHT22_t",
  "DHT22_h",
  "Hygrometer_1",
  "Hygrometer_2",
  "Hygrometer_3",
  "Hygrometer_4",
  "Battery"
};

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // Populate the readingsArray with dummy data.
    reading = random(0, 100);
    Serial.print("Reading: ");
    Serial.println(reading);
    readingsArray[i] = reading;
    delay(100);
  }

  Serial.print("readingsArray full");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    strcpy(mqttPackage, sensorIDArray[i]);     // copy topic to mqttPackage
    String tempStr = String(readingsArray[i]); // string from sensor float
    char* newChar;                             // I THINK THIS IS THE OFFENDING VARIABLE
    tempStr.toCharArray(newChar, tempStr.length() + 1); // string to char array
    strcat(mqttPackage, newChar);              // concatenate the chars to mqttPackage
    Serial.print("Element ");                  // Debug print the output.
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(mqttPackage);
    delay(100);
  }  
}
```

I am getting error 29 from the ESP8266, which suggests that the buffer is filling up with an unlimited variable.  Please can someone give me some pointers on where I am going wrong.

Please don't roast me.  I am an amateur coder just trying to learn, I have literally spent a week of evenings googling this as self help but have hit a block.

Comment: According to [the documentation for toCharArray](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/) you are supposed to supply a buffer, and the function will write into that buffer.  However what you actually do is supply an uninitialized pointer, which is not pointing anywhere.  I suggest not using `newChar` at all, instead output to a buffer you already set up , or just `Serial.print` directly from `tempStr` at the right time

Comment: `strcpy(mqttPackage, sensorIDArray[i]);` is also an error; `mqttPackage` is a pointer that is not pointing to anything, but you try to copy characters to where it is pointing

Comment: **"Please don't roast me"** - We don't roast people, we help people (Except we tend to help more people who have done their research ;P).

Comment: `char* sensorIDArray[]` should be `const char* sensorIDArray[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String::toCharArray` copies the characters managed by the `String` object into the buffer supplied.  You're passing `newChar` as the output buffer, but it's not pointing to any memory you can write to.  You need to allocate a buffer that you can write the string into:

```
char newChar[100] = {};
tempStr.toCharArray(newChar, 99); // 99 so we can't overwrite the last nul character
```

Note that if `tempStr` is longer than 99 `char`s, the first 99 will be written into `newChar`.

Your `strcpy` and `strcat` calls share the same issue.  They expect to fill a user-supplied buffer, but the pointer you're passing doesn't point to anything.

---

None of that dance is actually necessary though.  `String` directly supports concatenation, so you can just do something like

```
String mqttPackage = sensorIDArray[i];
mqttPackage += readingsArray[i];
```

Of course, you don't really need to concatinate the values in memory at all, since you're just printing them to the serial port.  You can just print them directly and let the `Serial` library worry about converting them

```
Serial.print("Element ");
Serial.print(i);
Serial.print(": ");
Serial.print(sensorIDArray[i]);
Serial.println(readingsArray[i];
```

Comment: I used `String mqttPackage = sensorIDArray[i];
mqttPackage += readingsArray[i];` and it worked.  I was starting to go down a whole rabbit run I didn't understand!!